# Error al correr app en dispositivo iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, iphone

Tengo una app que ya había probado en el mismo dispositivo pero la deje de correr durante unas dos semanas, durante ese tiempo note que cada vez que la intentaba abrir se cerraba automáticamente y hoy al volver a correr el proyecto en el dispositivo me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ademas en el celular la pantalla aparece en blanco. La probe en el simulador y si funciona.

¿Cuál es el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacer clean `(CMD+shift+K)`, clean folder `(CMD+ALT+shift+K)`, build `(CMD+B)` y luego ejecuta `(CMD+R)` el proyecto de nuevo en el dispositivo.

Answer (score 0):

La consola muestra un error que dice que no pudo cargar una librería, hay que solucionarlo, quizás reinstalando ***Xcode***.